Flow run-only permissions
I want some users with edit permissions to a list to run a manually triggered flow, and others not to be able. It looks like you can share run-only access with an AD group, but not with a SharePoint group. Is there a way to remove run-only permissions from a SharePoint group without removing edit permissions for the list? thanks.
